# Why does this combine subscription not deallocate in custom ViewModifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In the documentation for `assign` it says the following...

> The Subscribers/Assign instance created by this operator maintains a
> strong reference to object, and sets it to nil when the upstream
> publisher completes (either normally or with an error).

In the `ViewModifier` below the `assign` method in `subscribeToKeyboardChanges()` refers to self but self is a struct here so there's no way it can create a strong reference

- Why doesn't the subscription in `subscribeToKeyboardChanges()` get immediately deallocated?
- What is the actually happening here behind the scenes?

```
struct KeyboardHandler: ViewModifier {

    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, self.keyboardHeight)
            .animation(.default)
            .onAppear(perform: subscribeToKeyboardChanges)
    }

    private let keyboardWillShow = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
        .compactMap { $0.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect }
        .map { $0.height }

    private let keyboardWillHide =  NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
        .map { _ in CGFloat.zero }

    private func subscribeToKeyboardChanges() {
        _ = Publishers.Merge(keyboardWillShow, keyboardWillHide)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.self.keyboardHeight, on: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you`re referring to the wrong function description. Here is right one:

> **assign(to:on:)**
>
> Assigns a publisher’s output to a property of an object.
>
> ...
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An AnyCancellable instance. Call cancel() on this instance when you no
> longer want the publisher to automatically assign the property.
> Deinitializing this instance will also cancel automatic assignment.

So in your `subscribeToKeyboardChanges` example code it's expected that subscription will be canceled after function finishes. You have to keep strong reference to `AnyCancellable` return from `assign` to keep subscription in memory.

EDIT:

It appears that in this line `assign` copies `self` and holds it in the memory until `cancel()` call.

```
        .assign(to: \.self.keyboardHeight, on: self)
```

Therefore `View` that uses `KeyboardHandler` view modifier will never be deallocated with subscription and will eventually bloat the memory during navigation. For example, here is the screenshot after 3 navigations see 3 instances of `KeyboardHandler` still in the memory.

[image]

Comment: i just picked out a part of the description, it is the same one...

In my question the subscription is retained even though we aren’t storing it in a cancellable. So the question is how is it being retained here?